# Generate data where cell counts are random, but row sums always the same

Tags: r

I'm in a situation where I need to create a bunch of fake datasets where the sum of two variables is the same as in my real data, but the counts for each variable are random. Here's the setup:

```
>df
    X.1  X.2
1   145   30
2    55   73
```

The first row sums to 175, and the second to 128. What I'm looking for is a way to generate a data frame (or a bunch of data frames) like this:

```
>df.2
    X.1  X.2
1   100   75
2    90   38
```

In df.2, the cell counts have changed, but the rows still sum to the same table. The actual data has hundreds of rows, but only two variables if that helps. I've tried to figure out how to do this with `sample()` but haven't had any luck. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: You are sampling from a multinomial distribution, so `rmultinom` is what you want. Are the probabilities supposed to be equal for each cell?

Comment: Well, ideally it would be great if I could get the cell counts to be normally distributed with a mean of the "true" cell count.

Comment: Are you sure you mean *Normally* distributed. The multinomial distribution will ensure that the cell counts are poisson (conditional on the sum), but I don't think *normal* makes any sense, I've edited the answer to show how to do this.

Comment: Yes, you're right, poisson is more appropriate given the nature of the count. Thanks for catching that. Any way to make it generalizable to any number of rows, as in @thelatemail's answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are sampling from a multinomial distribution,

---

## edit

to allow for prespecified expected cell counts

- The multinomial distribution can be considered each cell as Poisson distribution (with expected cell count), conditional on the sum.

---

## EDIT 2

- allow for any number of rows / expected cell counts
- pass `expected` as the expected cell counts

---

note that `rmultinom` returns a matrix where each column is a multinomial sample, hence my use of `t` to create a single row matrix

```
replicates <- 10
expected <- data.frame(X1  = c(100,90,30),X2 = c(75,28,120))
##    X1  X2
## 1 100  75
## 2  90  28
## 3  30 120
data_samples <- lapply(seq(replicates), function(i, expected){
   # create a list of expected cell counts (list element = row of expected)
  .list <- lapply(apply(expected,1,list),unlist)
   # sample from these expected cell counts and recombine into a data.frame
   as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(.list, function(.x) t(rmultinom(n = 1, prob = .x,  size = sum(.x) )))))
   }, expected = expected)
```

This creates a list of `data.frames` with the appropriate properties

```
data_samples[[1]]
##    X1  X2
## 1 104  71
## 2  84  34
## 3  19 131


data_samples[[5]]
##   X1  X2
## 1 88  87
## 2 92  26
## 3 27 123
```

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you're looking for `r2dtable`?

```
> r2dtable(2, c(175,128), c(190, 113))
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  108   67
[2,]   82   46

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  114   61
[2,]   76   52
```

Also, here's a version of @mnel's answer that uses `rmultinom` to do the `n` replicates and then combines the results.  Not that it really matters if you only need a few replicates, but since `rmultinom` could do it, I thought I'd see how it might be done.

```
n <- 10
e <- cbind(X1  = c(100,90,30),X2 = c(75,28,120))
aperm(array(sapply(1:nrow(e), function(i) 
        rmultinom(n, rowSums(e)[i], (e/rowSums(e))[i,])),
      dim=c(ncol(e),n,nrow(e))), c(3,1,2))
```

Comment: + 1 , so simple., although it is not clear that the OP wants the column sums to be consistent.

Comment: Although this function requires specifying both a desired row *and*  column sum.

Comment: Column sum need not be the same, but that's actually a very nifty solution.

Comment: Given that you don't want the column sums to be the same, this approach might be nifty, but it is not correct.

Comment: You are all right that this also makes the column sums the same, which the OP did not require.  I do wonder what the OP is doing and which is really appropriate, but that would be a question for stats.stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

Data for use in answers:

```
test <- data.frame(X.1=c(145,55),X.2=c(30,73))
```

**A version using `sample`:**

```
t(sapply(
        rowSums(test),
        function(x) {
                one <- sample(1:x,1)
                two <- (x - one)
                result <- data.frame(one,two)
                names(result) <- names(test)
                return(result)
                }
         )
)
```

Results look like:

```
     X.1 X.2
[1,] 20  155
[2,] 127 1
```

or...

```
     X.1 X.2
[1,] 111 64 
[2,] 94  34
```

etc...

**Alternatively:**

Just add a bit of `jitter` to one of the numbers first then subtract this from the row sum.

```
t(apply(
        test,
        1,
        function(x) {
                rsum <- sum(x)
                one <- round(jitter(x[1],20,20),0)
                two <- (rsum - one)
                result <- c(one,two)
                names(result) <- names(test)
                return(result)
                }
    )
)
```

Result examples:

```
     X.1 X.2
[1,] 160  15
[2,]  47  81

     X.1 X.2
[1,] 127  48
[2,]  64  64
```

Comment: I do like the fact that this is generalizable to any number of rows, but it's not quite as flexible as the other answer

Answer (score 0):

If you what a total sample size of n= ..  say 40 and the number of cells is 4 with the number of columns = say 2 then the call should be:

```
rmultinom(2, size = 40/4, prob = c(0.5,0.5))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    3
[2,]    4    7
```

If you want a function to deliver this sort of result with specified probability per row then:

```
 my_mat_rand <- function(tot, coln, probs){
     rmultinom(coln, size = tot/length(probs), prob = probs) }

> my_mat_rand(tot=40, coln=2, probs  = c(0.5,0.5))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   11   10
[2,]    9   10
> my_mat_rand(40, 2, probs  = c(0.5,0.5))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8   13
[2,]   12    7
```

If you want the probabilities to be also "random" then use `runif` to specify the first and 1-`that-value` to specify the second element of the `probs` vector.