# Sampling a contingency table in R

Tags: r

I'd like to know if anyone can suggest an efficient method to sample a contingency table such that both the total number of observations and the column totals remain the same.

For example, in the following table where the rows are cases and the columns observations, I'd like to "scramble" the observations such that (a) the total number of observations is 54, and (b) the total number of observations in a variable (e.g., A) is <strike>16</strike> 18, the same as the original column total for A.

```
x<-matrix(c(
4,6,0,0,8,0,0,
1,1,1,1,4,0,0,
3,0,1,1,6,0,1,
2,1,0,0,1,0,0,
1,1,0,1,0,1,1,
2,0,0,2,1,2,0),
ncol=6,byrow=F)

colnames(x)<-c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
```

I've seen a discussion of contingency table sampling in which the cell frequencies are the source of the sampling probabilities for a sample(...) call. This won't work for my purposes because, among other reasons, the column totals do not remain equal to the original column totals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Patrick

EDIT

If there isn't an easy solution to this problem, perhaps someone can help me with my overly complicated (and failed) attempt. I first create a vector composed of the number of observations of each variable, e.g.,

```
m <- matrix()
v <- matrix()
for (h in 1:cols) {
    m <- rep(colnames(x)[h], sum(x[, h]))
    v <- c(v, m)}
```

I then sample it to randomly shuffle the observations, and bind it to a sample of values equal to the number of cases

```
    v<-sample(v,length(v))
    p<-sample(seq(1:nrow(x)),length(v),T)
    n<-as.data.frame(cbind(v,p))

    t(table(n))

      v
    p A B C D E F
    1 3 1 3 1 1 1
    2 1 1 0 0 0 0
    3 3 0 3 0 2 1
    4 3 2 1 2 1 2
    5 2 1 0 0 0 1
    6 3 2 3 1 1 1
    7 3 1 2 0 0 1

    colSums(t(table(n)))
    A  B  C  D  E  F 
   18  8 12  4  5  7
```

This works great except when the sample p fails to contain one of the values in the sequence (i.e., a "case" is missing), which as I've learned happens quite frequently, particularly when there are many iterations of the sample (e.g., 1000).

Thanks again,
Patrick

Comment: `sum(x[,"A"])` is `18` not `16` by my calculation.

Comment: Looks like this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031049/generate-data-where-cell-counts-are-random-but-row-sums-always-the-same

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion (and the correction) @thelatemail, but I'm not clear on how this method would work. Column totals aren't preserved (I need this feature) and row totals are (I don't want this feature).

Comment: @user1596424  Your comment about `the first row of column A should be able to have values from 1 to 18` and the one you showed are different.  Perhaps I misunderstood.  Also, can there be repeats if you want values between 1 to 18 for column `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be:

```
indx <- cbind(c(replicate(ncol(x), sample(1:nrow(x)))), c(col(x)))
x1 <- x
x1[] <- x[indx]
 
colSums(x1)
# A  B  C  D  E  F 
#18  8 12  4  5  7 

colSums(x)
#A  B  C  D  E  F 
#18  8 12  4  5  7 

sum(x1)
#[1] 54
```

#### Update

Based on the new info, which is confusing, may be this helps:

```
 cSum <- colSums(x)
 ind1 <- vector("list", length=ncol(x))
 for(i in seq_along(cSum)){
 repeat{ind1[[i]] <- sample(0:cSum[i], nrow(x)-1, replace=TRUE)
 if(sum(ind1[[i]]) <=cSum[i]) break
  }
 }

 x1 <- do.call(cbind, ind1)
 x2 <- rbind(x1,cSum-colSums(x1))
 colSums(x2)
# A  B  C  D  E  F 
#18  8 12  4  5  7 

sum(colSums(x2))
#[1] 54

  x2
 #    A B C D E F
 #[1,] 0 0 0 0 0 0
 #[2,] 9 5 1 2 0 1
 #[3,] 0 1 1 1 0 2
 #[4,] 0 0 4 0 0 1
 #[5,] 8 0 5 0 4 2
 #[6,] 0 0 1 0 1 1
 #[7,] 1 2 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, but unfortunately, neither your suggestion nor that suggested by @nico below will work. I need it to shuffle observations, not cases. For example, the first row of column A should be able to have values from 1 to 18. The same is true for the remaining rows of A with the constraint that their sum must be 18.

Comment: @user1596424 Sorry, I am following you.  If column `A` could have values from `1 to 18`, I guess, column `B` should have `1 to 8` and similarly for other columns.  So, `colSums` only matter and not `column values` ?

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @akrun, this is precisely what I needed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
x.swapped <- apply(x, MARGIN=2, FUN=sample)
```

`apply` applies the function passed in the parameter `FUN` to the columns (if `MARGIN` is 2, rows when it is 1) of the matrix `x`.
In this case we apply the `sample` function.
When called without extra parameters `sample` just reorders the element in the vector (see `?sample` for more help).

We can check that the totals in each column remain the same.

```
colSums(x)

 A  B  C  D  E  F 
18  8 12  4  5  7 

colSums(x.swapped)
 A  B  C  D  E  F 
18  8 12  4  5  7
```

And obviously

```
sum(x)
[1] 54

sum(x.swapped)
[1] 54
```

An example of output may be (note that, unless you fix the RNG seed using `set.seed` the result from `sample` will differ each time).

```
x

     A B C D E F
[1,] 4 1 3 2 1 2
[2,] 6 1 0 1 1 0
[3,] 0 1 1 0 0 0
[4,] 0 1 1 0 1 2
[5,] 8 4 6 1 0 1
[6,] 0 0 0 0 1 2
[7,] 0 0 1 0 1 0

x.swapped

     A B C D E F
[1,] 6 4 1 0 1 0
[2,] 0 1 3 2 0 0
[3,] 0 0 1 1 1 2
[4,] 0 0 0 0 1 2
[5,] 8 1 1 1 1 2
[6,] 4 1 0 0 1 0
[7,] 0 1 6 0 0 1
```