# Matrix with randomly generated number that adds up to fixed sum in R

Tags: r, matrix, random

I'm very new to R, and I'm trying to come up with `2 x 2` matrix with randomly generated numbers between 0 and 10, with a fixed total for the rows and columns, e.g. 20. I.e. the matrix could look something like this:

```
  1    10 
  4     5
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031049/generate-data-where-cell-counts-are-random-but-row-sums-always-the-same/12031205

Comment: Asking for 4 integers that sum to 29 is a partitioning. Search on "[r] partition"

Comment: you might be interested in the `magic` package, made to produce magic squares, which hold this property.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something on the below lines

```
repeat{
  x = sample(0:10,4)
  if(sum(x) == 20){
    x = matrix(data = x,nrow = 2,ncol = 2)
    break
  }
}
x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    1
[2,]    5   10
```